# BTC received in BECH32 (P2WPKH) format address not exist in Electrum

Tags: electrum, buy-bitcoins

I sent some BTC to a BECH32 (P2WPKH) format address. ([details of the transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/fc27d9b6d1baa9fdd2030515de7a12112b6df3d58e4dc2dbaf7a6e5d1aef6995))

I imported the private key(wif) in Electrum, but I can't find the income?

I am sure I sent to the right address and imported the right wif. How can I get the incomes?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you prefix p2wpkh: to the wif when importing? do you see the address under the addresses tab? view menu > show addresses if it's not there.